# Change legend geom type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a line plot that uses alpha as one of its scales.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is an error which results in alpha legends not working, even if they're working in the plot and Hadley has dismissed it as a Windows error.

As a work around, does anyone know how to change the geom in the legend from being a line to being a box (in the same way the fill of a bar chart would be presented)?

I've fiddled with the `overwrite_aes` argument of guide_legend however if that's the solution, I haven't worked out what argument to use.

Sample ggplot:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = y1, alpha = "test 1")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y2, alpha = "test 2")) +
    scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.5))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not perfect, but I found `override.aes()` to work.

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(
  x = 1:10, 
  y1 = runif(10), 
  y2 = runif(10)
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = y1, alpha = "test 1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y2, alpha = "test 2")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(1, 0.5)) + 
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 6))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

---

**Edit: Something "hackier"**

This is certainly hackier than the first one.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=x, y = y1), alpha=1) +
  geom_line(data=dat, aes(x=x, y = y2), alpha =.5) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=min(dat$x), xend=min(dat$x + .05*diff(range(dat$x))), 
                   y = max(c(dat$y1, dat$y2)), yend=max(c(dat$y1, dat$y2))), 
               alpha=1, size=6) +  
  geom_segment(aes(x=min(dat$x), xend=min(dat$x + .05*diff(range(dat$x))), 
                   y = max(c(dat$y1, dat$y2))-.025, yend=max(c(dat$y1, dat$y2))-.025), 
               alpha=.5, size=6) +  
  geom_text(aes(x=min(dat$x + .06*diff(range(dat$x))), 
                   y = max(c(dat$y1, dat$y2)), 
                label = "test1"), hjust=0) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=min(dat$x + .06*diff(range(dat$x))), 
                   y = max(c(dat$y1, dat$y2))-.025, 
                label = "test2"), hjust=0)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately is not 'hacky' enough for my purposes. Since the graphical error is a line, I still get the same problem: my legend is not displaying any elements with an alpha value < 1.

I'd submit a picture, but I'm currently at work where they're all blocked.

I'm trying to create a new graphical object altogether in hopes that it doesn't have the same issue.

Comment: @DanielV I added a "hackier" solution that may suit your needs.

Comment: That is hackier, but I already have a legend for colour and linetype so this won't work either. Its the weekend more but I think I'm going to create new geoms with created NA position values in the dataset.